# Why doesn't this /give command work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically I have this command,

```
give @p sign 1 0
{
    BlockEntityTag:{
        Text2:"{\"text\":\"Don't Click me\",\"strikethrough\":true}",
        Text3:"{
            \"text\":\"Click Me!\",
            \"italic\":true,
            \"underlined\":true,
            \"clickEvent\":{
                \"action\":\"run_command\",
                \"value\":\"/setblock ~ ~100 ~ repeating_command_block{
                    Command:\\"/gamemode creative @a\\",
                    auto:1}
                \"
            }
        }"
    },
    display:{
        Name:"Custom Sign"
    }
}
```

Which in theory, when activated it should spawn a sign which when placed and right-clicked should spawn a repeating command block 100 blocks in the air which sets everyone in the server (@a) to creative mode. Although when I try to use it, only the "/give @p) part isn't red. I don't know much about commands but I can't seem to find anything wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated. Also I'm in version 1.16.4.

Comment: after posting the thread, basically i've scrapped the idea and have switched  to a new idea. if anyone wants to solve it for anyone who might wanna use it is free to do so. thanks bye

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 you can assume Java cause 1.16.4 only exists in Java - there's no way this was a typo from 1.14.50 (education) or 1.16.201 (bedrock)

Comment: Is this command written in a function? If so, you can't use newlines as the interpreter treats every new line as a new command. Also, do you know if there's any error output when running the command?

Comment: @Ben It's not written with line breaks. That was my edit, to expand the NBT data to make it easier to read. It was all one one line before, but that made it impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things wrong with this command:

Firstly, the `sign` item name has been renamed to `oak_sign` (for definite future-proofness, I'd recommend you use `minecraft:oak_sign` instead).

Secondly, positioning for the NBT tag of an item is *right after* the item name itself. For example:

```
/give @p minecraft:oak_sign{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"My Custom Name\"}"}} 1
```

Thirdly, I tried running your exact command and the syntax for the NBT data didn't seem to be correct. I can't figure out why, but if anyone can they should feel free to edit this answer